# Multiple WizardSmallImageFiles in Inno Setup 5.5.9

Tags: inno-setup

To support different DPI settings, I want to provide several `WizardSmallImageFile` images. According to the documentation, this is how it should work:

http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_wizardsmallimagefile

```
WizardSmallImageFile=image_x140.bmp,image_x123.bmp
```

When compiling I get an error message:

> Could not read "R:\my_installer\image_x140.bmp,image_x123.bmp". Error:
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

Is this function no longer supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is supported, but only since recent [Inno Setup 5.6.0](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm#5.6.0).

So you most probably need to upgrade your copy of Inno Setup.

Comment: Also, you can use wildcards, like `*.bmp`.

Comment: What I don't understand is why the images documented are not "proportionate" to each other.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle Just a guess: It's probably because the window size scales with font size. And the font height and width probably does not scale proportionally.